# Como restaurar una ventana de JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo un `JFrame` principal el cual se minimiza 
 con `(setExtendedState(ICONIFIED));` cuando se abre otra ventana desde los paneles de su interior.

Lo que necesito es que cuando se cierre esa otra ventana que se abrio el `JFrame` principal vuelva a estar restaurado mas no maximizado, ya que me daña el diseño y es aspecto con `(Gestion.ges.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);)`

Necesito el metodo  que pueda indicarle al Jframe que debe de volver a su estado original.

Answer (score 1):

Yo he hecho esto, Tal vez le sirva a alguien mas.

//Variable booleana definida en los campos de clase

```
    if(state == false){
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.jButton2.setText("Restaurar");
        state = true;

    }else if(state){
        this.setExtendedState(NORMAL);
        this.jButton2.setText("maximizar");
        state = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he conseguido... despues de mucho investigar top con lo que neceitaba.
en su efecto necesitva `Gestion.ges.setExtendedState(NORMAL)`. la constante normal eso era lo unico que me hacia falta